# Upload images to google cloud with php

Tags: image, upload, google-cloud-storage

My problem is the following, I have an application developed in PHP, wich allows to upload images to the server by means of ajax, but now I need to change the storage of that images to google cloud and serve them from there, for that I have created a bucket and I tested the following code that does not work.

```
<?php
$options = [ "gs" => [ "Content-Type" => "text/plain" ]];
$ctx = stream_context_create($options);
file_put_contents("gs://myimages/hello.txt", "Hello", 0, $ctx);
?>
```

The error is this: file_put_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "gs" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload1\gmail\index.php on line 4

But what I need is just to save the images in google cloud, because my server will be running in another enterprise, would this be possible?

And how to enable gs://,

I tried with this http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-default.php and I don't understand how to get it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used GCS with PHP on App Engine, but if you're not running on App Engine, it's unlikely that your runtime has a wrapper for `gs://` URLs.

To run your application outside of App Engine, Google provide XML and (experimental) JSON APIs.  Documentation, libraries and a sample application are [available](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/libraries) on the GCS developer website.